# Extracting styles from material ui component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**AppBar** applies some styles for children of specific types. Unfortunately it happens only to direct children

```
<AppBar title="first" iconElementRight={
    <FlatButton label="first" />
}/>
<AppBar title="second" iconElementRight={
    <div>
        <FlatButton label="second" /> <!-- styles are not applied -->
    </div>
}/>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zcrrtk0/)

Hopefully, it seems like **AppBar** component exposes getStyles method.

```
exports.getStyles = getStyles;
```

Unfortunately I cannot figure out way to consume it. Is there are any way do it rather than redefining all styles on my own?

PS
I'm importing components in with import directive

```
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Get the styles from AppBar and override the `<FlatButton label="second" />` text color ? Or just get the styles from AppBar?

Comment: @QoP: I want to make FlatButton and some IconMenu that I'm putting there styled as they were specified as direct children of iconElementRight. To do that I'm planning to get styles from AppBar and override it for my elements (that should be about colour and position).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MuiThemeProvider` adds a `muiTheme` object to the context so you can get all the styles from there.

```
Comp.contextTypes = {
  muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
}

render: function () {
        let {appBar} = this.context.muiTheme; // appBar styles here
        ...
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zcrrtk0/2/)

Comment: Thank you. I think this is way better than hardcoding color in own component. However, it would be way nice to get exact style from https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/AppBar/AppBar.js#L55 then it I would not need to do the same for other properties + it would be autoupdated on AppBar changes. It also seems that getStyles function is exported. Do you think that there is way to call it somehow?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, seems like an "internal" function. You can try to import it using `import {getStyles} from 'material-ui/AppBar/AppBar'` and call it using getStyles(this.props,this.context), but not sure if it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a custom component to reroute the styles to your desired child. This version only forwards `style` to the child and the rest stay on the wrapping component (a `<div>` by default) but could be customized to your requirements.

```js
        const StyleDelegate = function (props) {
  const {component: Component, children, style, ...rest} = props;
  // pass style to the only child and everything else to the component
  // could be further customized for other props
  return (
      <Component {...rest}>
          {React.cloneElement(children, {style})}
      </Component>
  );
};

StyleDelegate.defaultProps = {
    component: 'div'
};

const AppBar = function (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.title}
      {React.cloneElement(props.iconElementRight, {style: {color: 'blue'}})}
    </div>
  );
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<AppBar
                  iconElementRight={<StyleDelegate><span>Icon</span></StyleDelegate>}
                  title="title" />,
                document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```